# Topology Manager and discovery service

Tags: content-delivery, web8

I am unable to publish any item in Tridion with new publishing infrastructure Business Process Type, its status is showing "waiting for publish" only.

We have successfully installed Topology Manager and Discovery service in the CME machine and followed below steps to configure the Topology Manager:

```
Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id BlogPostDev -Name BlogPostDev -EnvironmentPurposes Dev

Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id SampleCD -EnvironmentPurpose Dev -DiscoveryEndpointUrl "http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc" -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId cmuser -ClientSecret CMUserP@ssw0rd 

Add-TtmCdTopology -Id BlogTopology -Name "Blog Topology" -CdTopologyTypeId BlogPostDev -CdEnvironmentIds SampleCD

Add-TtmWebsite -Id DevTestSite -CdEnvironmentId SampleCD -BaseUrls "http://example.com" 

Add-TtmWebApplication -Id DevWebApp_Test -WebsiteId DevTestSite -ContextUrl "/" 

Add-TtmMapping 

Add-TtmCmEnvironment -WebsiteRootUrl http://xx.xx.x.xxx -AuthenticationType Basic -Username cmeuser -Password passowrd
```

Where and how to configure the Content Deployer (linux machine) path in Discovery service, if we have multiple Content Deployers?

What is the `DiscoveryEndpointUrl` in our case, is it http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc or Content Deployer (linux)?

Can you provide details on above 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The key is to have the mapping between the Publication and the Business Process Type.  And, in the Publication properties, select to use the Business Process Type (I always forget this step).  Finally, make sure in the Target from your Business Process Type, that you have enabled all users.  To troubleshoot, look at the cd_core logs from the discovery service and deployer service.  Also, it is helpful to access the URLs of your micro-services to confirm they are working.

Comment: You should normally not create your own `CmEnvironment` in Topology Manager; the CM installer does that for you.

Comment: How did you define the `Mapping` in Topology Manager (I only see `Add-TtmMapping`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Discovery Service is supposed to be installed on your CD environment -- not your CM environment (that one has the Topology Manager).

You then tell the Topology Manager about the different CD environments you have (`Add-TtmCdEnvironment`), including the URL to its Discovery Service. Topology Manager will then talk to that Discovery Service.

Your CD environment could be the Linux machine with your Deployer -- or it could be a separate machine. That just depends on your infrastructure.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple DeployerCapability <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://localhost/cd_upload/httpupload"> in cd_storage_conf.xml ? if yes how can I add Add-TtmCdEnvironment in Topology manager ? Can you please provide details.

Comment: The short answer is no. Have a look at this question & answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15157/setting-multiple-deployer-on-web8